# Can't create an alias in tcsh shell when trying to sed some string with .*

Tags: sed, alias, tcsh, csh

I'm trying to create this alias in **tcsh** shell:

```
 alias repeat 'zgrep -i __NCELAB_SNAPSHO \!* | grep -v make | grep -v Flags | sed 's#CODE_COVERAGE_TYPES.*TEST_DONE=1##g''
```

And getting an error:

```
alias: No match.
```

Please advise me what should I do to generate this alias?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to see the issue right there in your question. Look at the syntax highlighting. The problem is that you have a single quote around the alias, but also use a single quote inside it for the `sed` command. Try this instead:

```
alias repeat "zgrep -i __NCELAB_SNAPSHO \!* | grep -v make | grep -v Flags | sed 's#CODE_COVERAGE_TYPES.*TEST_DONE=1##g'"
```

Or:

```
alias repeat 'zgrep -i __NCELAB_SNAPSHO \!* | grep -v make | grep -v Flags | sed "s#CODE_COVERAGE_TYPES.*TEST_DONE=1##g"'
```